# What does it mean for one function to be big O and/or little, Omega, or big Theta of another function?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Lets say I have two functions f(n) and g(n) and I would have to determine whether f(n) is Big O and/or little o, Omega, or Big Theta of g(n).

How would you determine that using f(n)=sqrt(n) and g(n)=log(n)?

I was thinking that since f(n) grows faster it is Omega of g(n).  Am I understanding that correctly or do I have that backwards?

Comment: Since $f(n)$ grows "strictly faster" asymptotically speaking, it is neither $O(g(n))$ nor $o(g(n))$. If it were the same speed then you would have $O(g(n))$ but not $o(g(n))$.

Comment: $o,O,\Theta,\Omega$ are analogous to $<,\le,=,\ge$ respectively.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations

Answer (score 1):

In your examples(taking $\log=\ln$) as we have $g(n)=\ln n \lt \sqrt{n}=f(n)$, then we can say, that $g(n)=\ln n = O(\sqrt{n}) = O(f(n))$. So, $f$ "grows faster" we can understand as $g \in O(f)$. In this case we can say, that also $\ln n = o(\sqrt{n})$, because $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}}=0$, so, $f$ "grows strictly faster" we can understand as $g \in o(f)$.

But we cannot generalize this property as shows example $1+\frac{1}{n}\in O(1)$, but $1+\frac{1}{n}\notin o(1)$ .

In general we have $f\in o(g) \Rightarrow f\in O(g)$ i.e. $o(g) \subset O(g)$.